# How to estimate THD?

Tags: audio, distortion

I have a signal source that I can digitise and read.  It produces mainly a 50Hz sine wave, but there is distortion as well.  I'd like to estimate the total harmonic distortion for this signal.  I've looked at some on line resources that seem algebraically complicated.  Is there some simpler estimate I can make?  I have the following spectrum of the signal:

[image: Spectrum analysis]

and a waveform graph (black line):

[image: Waveform]

I don't have access to any specialised hardware, but I have Scope (sound card based oscilloscope) and Audacity like software...

Comment: If you have Audacity, then you can use *Distortion Analyser* plugin.

Comment: @jojek My Audacity (v2.1.2) doesn't have one of those unfortunately...

Comment: You have to [**download**](http://forum.audacityteam.org/download/file.php?id=3073&sid=686ecaba9e630c0dba520df0612e1d5a) it. But anyway I wouldn't use Audacity for that. Just install Python and do the analysis in there. I believe that endolith once did a script for THD estimation.

Comment: @jojek Right, done that.  Plug in works, but how much sample does it need to work?  It doesn't work on the 5 sec clip I currently have...

Comment: Probably 20 seconds or so. If feel like it, then I suggest to use Python instead ;)

Comment: @jojek  Can't.  I'm a BBC Basic and Java type.  Brain's not large enough to learn a third language.  I'll rebuild my kit to get a larger sample.  Thanks jojek.

Comment: My first thought is to match the amplitude and frequency and offset to recreate a perfect sine wave, and then subtract your matched waveform from your actual and your residual would be your distortion (noise).  Take the rms of the noise to get your noise level Nrms. The signal level is Vpeak/sqrt(2) so the THD in dB would be 20*log10(Vpeak/(sqrt(2)*Nrms). I recommend sweeping (fine tune) over amplitude values to minimize the rms noise and thereby achieve the best estimate.  I am not confident this is the "best" answer so only give it as a comment for others to second or refute .

Comment: @DanBoschen Interesting.  I didn't know that THD could be defined like this.  The main frequency is exactly 50Hz - it's mains hum.  I can work with that too.

Comment: I would get additional opinions on my approach; my approach would give you the total distortion, not limited to the "harmonic" distortion which should be limited to multiples of your fundamental frequency, hence my hesitation with the method.

Comment: @DanBoschen Noted.  My device doesn't produce harmonics at all, so your total distortion is probably a better metric of the non "sinusoidality" of the output.  It's a bit like the R value for a statistical goodness of fit.

Comment: Yes agreed;  If you want a metric as to how good your sine wave is to a pure sine wave, then this would be a good approach. Note- another very good approach would be to calculate the correlation coefficient. If you need more details on that I can provide it as my answer- SIgnal to Total Distortion Ratio and the Correlation Coefficient are directly related.

Comment: If you do want me to do that; provide details on the correlation coefficient, rho and how it is related to SNR and in general a quality metric of how well your signal matches a reference signal, it would probably be best to rephrase your question accordingly first.